# How can one find the square roots of a complex number (say -7+13i, or more generally a+bi) using de Moivre's formula?

Tags: complex-numbers

> How can one find the square roots of a complex number (say $-7+13i$, or more generally $a+bi$) using de Moivre's formula?

I've begun a course on complex variables recently and one of the first things we've covered is complex numbers in polar form, where de Moivre's formula emerges. But in this, I know it can be used to find the two square roots of a complex number, but I'm really not sure how. I feel I might be getting lost in the trigonometry.

Comment: It will be better for this case to use the algebraic form of complex numbers. Consider $x + i y$ a square root of $-7 + 13 i$ then : 
$$-7 + 13 i = x^2 - y^2 + 2 i x y$$
and :
$$x^2 + y^2 = |x + i y|^2 = \sqrt{7^2 + 13^2}$$
Use the system :
$$\left\{\begin{array}{lcl} x^2 - y^2 & = & -7 \\ x^2 + y^2 & = &  7^2 + 13^2 \end{array}\right.$$
to determiner $x^2$ and $y^2$ and the equation $2 x y = 13$ for the sign of $x$ and $y$.

Comment: A comment rather than an answer as this is surely a duplicate and has been asked many times but Step 1) (the hard step) Convert $a+bi$ to $r e^{\theta i}=re^{\theta i+2k\pi i}$ form.  then Step 2) (the easy step) $(re^{\theta i+2k\pi i})^{\frac 12}=r^{\frac 12} e^{\frac \theta 2i +k\pi} =\sqrt r e^{\frac \theta 2i},\sqrt r e^{(\frac \theta 2 +\pi)i}$.  .... Now step 1.... to be continued.....

Comment: ....$z=a+bi =|z|( \frac a{|z|} + i\frac b{|z|})=|z|(\frac a{\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}} + i\frac b{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}})$.  As $(\frac {a}{\sqrt{|z|}})^2 + (\frac {b}{|z|})^2 = \frac {a^2+b^2}{a^2 + b^2}= 1$ then $(\frac a{|z|},\frac b{|z|}$ is on the unit circle and there is a unique $\theta$ so that $\frac a{|z|}=\cos \theta$ and $\frac b{|z|}=\sin\theta$. To find that that $\theta$ note $\tan \theta=\frac {\frac{b}{|z|}}{\frac {a}{|z|}}=\frac ba$ so $\theta = \arctan \frac ba$.  So $z=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}(\cos \arcsin \frac ba+i\sin \arcsin \frac ba)=|z|e^{\arcsin \frac{Re(z)}{Im(z)}i}$.

Answer (score 1):

Write the complex number $z$ as $r(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)$ and use De'Moivre's formula to claim that
$$\sqrt z=r^{\frac 12}\left(\cos \left(\frac \theta 2\right)+i\sin \left(\frac \theta 2\right)\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

Well, we know that:

$$\text{z}=\Re\left(\text{z}\right)+\Im\left(\text{z}\right)i=\left|\text{z}\right|\exp\left(\left(\text{Arg}\left(\text{z}\right)+2\pi\text{k}\right)i\right)\tag1$$

Where $\text{Arg}\left(\text{z}\right)$ is the principle value of the argument, $\text{k}\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $\left|\text{z}\right|=\sqrt{\Re\left(\text{z}\right)^2+\Im\left(\text{z}\right)^2}$.

Now, taking the square root gives:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\sqrt{\text{z}}&=\text{z}^\frac{1}{2}\\
\\
&=\left(\left|\text{z}\right|\exp\left(\left(\text{Arg}\left(\text{z}\right)+2\pi\text{k}\right)i\right)\right)^\frac{1}{2}\\
\\
&=\left|\text{z}\right|^\frac{1}{2}\cdot\exp\left(\frac{1}{2}\cdot\left(\text{Arg}\left(\text{z}\right)+2\pi\text{k}\right)i\right)\\
\\
&=\sqrt{\left|\text{z}\right|}\cdot\exp\left(\left(\frac{\text{Arg}\left(\text{z}\right)}{2}+\pi\text{k}\right)i\right)\\
\\
&=\sqrt{\left|\text{z}\right|}\cos\left(\frac{\text{Arg}\left(\text{z}\right)}{2}+\pi\text{k}\right)+\sqrt{\left|\text{z}\right|}\sin\left(\frac{\text{Arg}\left(\text{z}\right)}{2}+\pi\text{k}\right)i
\end{split}\tag2
\end{equation}

Answer (score 1):

First you should find $r$ and $\theta$ like below. Since $r^2=a^2+b^2$

$$\sqrt{a^2+b^2}=\sqrt{r^2}=\begin{cases}
r,~~~r>0\\
-r,~~~r<0
\end{cases}$$

But since $r$ is positive,

$$r=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$$

Also $\tan\theta=\frac ba$, So

$$\operatorname{Arctan}\frac ba=\operatorname{Arctan}(\tan\theta)=\begin{cases}
\theta,~~~\text{first quadrant}\\
\theta-\pi,~~~\text{second and third quadrants}\\
\theta-2\pi,~~~\text{fourth quadrant}
\end{cases}$$

and

$$\theta=\begin{cases}
\operatorname{Arctan}\frac ba,~~~(a,b>0)\\
\pi+\operatorname{Arctan}\frac ba,~~~(a<0)\\
2\pi+\operatorname{Arctan}\frac ba,~~~(a>0,b<0)
\end{cases}$$

Then

$$\begin{align}
\sqrt z&=\sqrt r\left(\cos\left(\frac{\theta+2k\pi}2\right)+i\sin\left(\frac{\theta+2k\pi}2\right)\right), k=0,1\\
&=\pm\sqrt{r}\left(\cos\left(\frac{\theta}2\right)+i\sin\left(\frac{\theta}2\right)\right)
\end{align}$$